# C# MIDI Keyboard Output Detector and Print

Tags: c#, midi

When I'm pressing single button in MIDI keyboard, what C# code can I use to determine which key has been pressed?

Comment: Are you looking for C# program code to detect this key press? Or just what MIDI codes correspond to what keys?

Comment: I just want know the key I'm pressing or any unique id, after that I can change it to the original one, please help me

Comment: Right, so when you press a key on a MIDI keyboard, you want to read a numerical code for that, using a C# operation? What do you mean by "I can change it to the original one"?

Comment: Yes, at the moment, that's fine for me. What I meant is, getting the keyboard output, I will change it to the exact midi output, like print each letter into the notepad, if I can get exact midi keypress values, that's great, make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Meet the Midi.NET library or similar.